# What Scriptures describe Rasaleela of Rudra (Shiva) with Krishna?

Tags: shiva, krishna, puranas

Some blogs on internet say Lord Shiva (in human form "Rudra") participated in divine dance (*Rasaleela*) with Krishna at Vrindavan.

Did Bhagavatam or any Purana mention Shiva (Rudra) dancing with Krishna?

[image]

Comment: This photo doesn't seem to be raas leela.

Comment: @KrishnaShweta how does it look then?

Comment: If u see the lyrics of the devotional song I mentioned then u will understand why I said. Please have a look at that.

Answer (score 5):

While it is quite a popular belief (even one that I believe), according to Bhagavatam, Lord Shiva is nowhere mentioned in the Rasa Leela; He is only used as a simile like:
Just like one should not imitate Lord Shiva in drinking poison, one should not imitate Lord Krsna in his Rasa Leela pastimes.

But in Vrindavana, there is a temple for Lord Gopeshvara Mahadeva, which you can read about [here](http://mathuravisit.com/vrindavan/gopesvara-mahadeva-temple.html).

Comment: But legend of temple says Shiva participated in Rasaleela but Bagavatam didn't mention this. But Temples are proof to certain stories in Mythology.

Comment: That is why I said, in Bhagavatam it is not there. But maybe since Shukabrahma Rshi would have become lost to the world if he said these leelas, he didn't narrate them to Parikshit.

Comment: What do you mean "lost to the world"?

Comment: Thannai Marandha Nilai.

Comment: @AnilKumar I wasn't saying **Shiva** imitated Krsna. Sukabrahma said, just like **we** should not imitate Shiva, **we** should not imitate Krsna.

Comment: I think Bhagavatam even don't mention Radha..

Comment: @YDS that is true. It doesn't mention her name, though many acharyas have identified the places where she as a character speaks in Bhagavatam.

Comment: In any case I think my answer above is inadequate since it doesn't answer the question. Answered it when I was new to this site. :)