# What are the events when Lord Shiva and Lord Krishna met?

Tags: shiva, krishna

1. This photo is one event,

[image]

2. This is the [devotional song](https://www.bhajanganga.com/bhajan/lyrics/id/646/title/ik-din-vo-bhole-bhandaari-ban-karke-braj-ki-naari-vrindavan-aa-gaye) that talks about another event,

> भोले भंडारी बन करके ब्रज की नारी वृन्दावन आ गए

I want to know both the stories and are there any other times when They met?

**Edit:** [What Scriptures describe Rasaleela of Rudra (Shiva) with Krishna?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9476/what-scriptures-describe-rasaleela-of-rudra-shiva-with-krishna) is already there.

So, I want reference for first event and are there any other times They met apart from these two?

Comment: Related [What Scriptures describe Rasaleela of Rudra (Shiva) with Krishna?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9476/3500).

Comment: The Qn should mention "Shankara" instead of "Shiva". See: [What's the difference among "Shiva" vs "Shankara" vs "Rudra"?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20218/1049)

Answer (score 12):

Lord Shiva met Lord Krishna several times and we can find description in Mahabharata and several Puranas.

Here are some of the events from Mahabharata:

**1) Meeting with Lord Shiva while getting the boon for getting Samba (son of Lord Krishna) and several other boons:**

This is described in [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13a015.htm) of Mahabharata:

> **"The blessed Krishna said,** 'Bowing my head with great joy unto that mass of energy and effulgence, I said these words unto the great Deity, with a heart filled with gladness,--Firmness in virtue, the slaughter of foes in battle, the highest fame, the greatest might, devotion to Yoga, thy adjacence, and hundreds upon hundreds of children, these are the boons I solicit of thee,-- **So be it,--said Sankara** repeating the words I had uttered. After this, the mother of the universe, the upholders of all things, who cleanses, all things, viz., the spouse of Sarva, that vast receptacle of penances said with a restrained soul these words unto me,--'The puissant Mahadeva has granted thee, O sinless one, a son who shall be named Samva. Do thou take from me also eight boons which thou choosest. I shall certainly grant them to thee.

**2) Meeting while providing Pashupatastra for Arjuna the second time:**

This is described in [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07077.htm) of Mahabharata:

> Beholding those two, viz., Nara and Narayana arrived, **Bhava of cheerful soul, smilingly said unto them, 'Welcome are ye,** ye foremost of men! Rise up and let the fatigue of your journey be over. What, O heroes, is the desire in your heart? Let it be uttered quickly. What is the business that has brought you hither? I will accomplish it and do what would benefit you. I will grant everything ye may desire., Hearing those words of the god, they both rose. And then with joined hands, the faultless Vasudeva and Arjuna, both of great wisdom, began to gratify that high-souled deity with an excellent hymn. **And Krishna and Arjuna said,** 'We bow to Bhava, to Sarva, to Rudra, to the boon-giving deity. We bow to the lord of all creatures endued with life, to the god who is always fierce, to him who is called Kapardin! We bow to Mahadeva, to Bhima, to the Three-eyed, to him who is peace and contentment.

**3) Meeting during Banasura Yuddha:**

 
This is described in [this chapter](http://mahabharata-resources.org/harivamsa/vishnuparva/hv_2_125.html) and preceding chapters of Harivamsha of Mahabharata:

> **As the three eyed lord placed the arrow on the bow for shooting, the great soul, the son of vasudeva (kR^iShNa), the one who knows the minds (of others), came to know.** The best among men, (kR^iShNa) took up an arrow named jR^imbhaNaM. The one with great power, the one who does things quickly, made hara yawn.

**4) Meeting after Krishna fought with Indra:**

 
This is described in [this chapter](http://mahabharata-resources.org/harivamsa/vishnuparva/hv_2_074.html) of Harivamsha, where Krishna went to Swarga to get Parijata and fights with Indra and after it in the evening, Lord Krishna invokes Lord Rudra and meets with him:

> Then hari, the one without any decline, took water from ga~NgA and fruits of Aegle Marmelos (bilva, the wood-apple tree) and invoked the Lord rudra, the lord of all gods.**Then the lord, the great lord shiva, accompanied by umA and the gaNa attending him arrived there** and stood above the water of ga~Nga and the bilva fruits.

There can be other several events of meeting of Maheswara and Vasudeva. I shall keep on updating the answer.

Answer (score 10):

I do not know the references of any of the both events you have mentioned. I am answering only this part:

#### are there any other times they met apart from these two?

1. One instance I found is when the there is a fight between Lord Krishna and Banasura, then Lord Shiva came from the side of Banasura. It is mentioned in [Shrimada Bhagavatam, Canto 10, Chapter 63](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/63).

> SB 10.63.6 — Lord Rudra, accompanied by his son Kārtikeya and the Pramathas, came riding on Nandi, his bull carrier, to fight Balarāma and Kṛṣṇa on Bāṇa’s behalf.

2. Second instance is found when Lord Krishna obtained Pashupata Vrata to obtain a son like Lord Shiva. Then Lord Shiva blessed him with a son naming Samba. It is mentioned in [Chapter one Acquisition of sons by Sri Krishna in Vaayaveeyasamhita section two of Shiva Purana (Pg No- 1912)](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/bitstream/10689/12960/7/Chapter5_1893-1972p.pdf). I have credited this reference from [this answer by TheDestroyer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9986/where-is-it-mentioned-that-krishna-and-rama-worshipped-shiva-lingam/9995#9995)

> Due to that penance, at the end of year, Lord Shiva, equipped with great splendor and accompanied by his Ganas and Parvati appeared there.
>
> After bowing to Shiva of handsome features, who appeared before him for granting boons, Krishna eulogized him with palms joined in reverence.
>
> Krishna of composed mind obtained his son Samba of good qualities bequeathed by Siva who was delighted by penance.

Answer (score 1):

Once Goddess Parvati was going to Gokul for Maharasa. Lord Shiva asked him" Where are you Going?" Maa Parvati Said" Going to Gokul for Maharasa". Lord Shiva also wanted to go to Maharasa But in Maharasa Only Womens were Allowed. So, Lord Shiva Find the Solution and decorate himself as a Women like "Gopi" to meet Shri Krishna and to atend Maharasa.
Here is the Beautiful Hindi Bhajan which is Based on Same Story

[भोले भंडारी बन करके ब्रज की नारी वृन्दावन आ गए](https://www.marvadibhajan.com/2020/07/ek-din-wo-bhole-bhandari-ban-karke-brij-nari-gokul-me-aa-gaye-.html)