# Did Siva come to Gokula to view the baby Krishna?

Tags: shiva, krishna

It is said that he wanted to see the beauty of the baby Krishna.

For the **100 millionth time**, the other question doesn't even remotely answer this question and has no direct citations from scripture whatsoever.

Here is a story - is this from real scripture?

http://www.bhagavatam-katha.com/vrindavan-story-lord-siva-visit-to-sri-krishna-in-gokula/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What Scriptures describe Rasaleela of Rudra (Shiva) with Krishna?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9476/what-scriptures-describe-rasaleela-of-rudra-shiva-with-krishna)

Comment: You might want to strike off the *Rasa leela* part, and limit it just to Lord *Shiva* coming to visit the newly born infant *Shri Krishna*.

Comment: Thanks, @Vivikta